# Running 2 different cameras using usb_cam

Tags: roslaunch, stereo, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using the usb_cam package and I'm trying to launch my 2 cameras at the same time. I'm using the following launch file:

```
<launch>
 <group ns="camera1">
  <node name="usb_cam1" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
 </group>

<group ns="camera2">
  <node name="usb_cam2" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video2" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
 </group>
</launch>
```

I see that my two cameras launch (there is a light that turns on) but I don't get any images. My terminal gives me this msg:

`$ roslaunch 2cams_test.launch
... logging to /home/davicho/.ros/log/3a1f0a6e-6889-11e5-8461-0071cc3abcf5/roslaunch-davicho-3304.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.`

started roslaunch server http://davicho:51904/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /camera1/image_view/autosize: True
- /camera1/usb_cam1/camera_frame_id: usb_cam
- /camera1/usb_cam1/image_height: 480
- /camera1/usb_cam1/image_width: 640
- /camera1/usb_cam1/io_method: mmap
- /camera1/usb_cam1/pixel_format: mjpeg
- /camera1/usb_cam1/video_device: /dev/video1
- /camera2/image_view/autosize: True
- /camera2/usb_cam2/camera_frame_id: usb_cam
- /camera2/usb_cam2/image_height: 480
- /camera2/usb_cam2/image_width: 640
- /camera2/usb_cam2/io_method: mmap
- /camera2/usb_cam2/pixel_format: mjpeg
- /camera2/usb_cam2/video_device: /dev/video2
- /rosdistro: indigo
- /rosversion: 1.11.13

NODES
/camera2/
image_view (image_view/image_view)
usb_cam2 (usb_cam/usb_cam_node)
/camera1/
image_view (image_view/image_view)
usb_cam1 (usb_cam/usb_cam_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3316]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 3a1f0a6e-6889-11e5-8461-0071cc3abcf5
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3329]
started core service [/rosout]
process[camera1/usb_cam1-2]: started with pid [3346]
process[camera1/image_view-3]: started with pid [3356]
process[camera2/usb_cam2-4]: started with pid [3357]
process[camera2/image_view-5]: started with pid [3376]
[ INFO] [1443737430.656950901]: Using transport "raw"

(image_raw:3356): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
[ INFO] [1443737430.778414332]: Using transport "raw"

(image_raw:3376): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
[ INFO] [1443737431.047213737]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1443737431.047358391]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/davicho/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1443737431.047471646]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/davicho/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1443737431.047526261]: Camera calibration file /home/davicho/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1443737431.047583711]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video1) at 640x480 via mmap (mjpeg) at 30 FPS
[ WARN] [1443737431.075626997]: unknown control 'focus_auto'

[ERROR] [1443737431.076149773]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...
[ INFO] [1443737431.082241865]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1443737431.082405128]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/davicho/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1443737431.082533707]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/davicho/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1443737431.082587458]: Camera calibration file /home/davicho/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1443737431.082646527]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video2) at 640x480 via mmap (mjpeg) at 30 FPS
[ WARN] [1443737431.111333288]: unknown control 'focus_auto'

[ERROR] [1443737431.111752759]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

Why is this happening? I've been reading about launch files, and I understood that by using two different nodes this would be able to launch multiple cameras, but I'm not succeeding.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218573/running-2-different-cameras-using-usb_cam/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2015-10-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on 2018-12-12**:
Hi Sir,
I used you method for my dual usb cameras and it works very well. However, in the terminal it throws heaps of the following warnings. Any idea how to solve it? Thanks
[swscaler @ 0x2be20a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

First you need to change from

```
<param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
```

to

```
<param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
```

Then you need to remap topic name from

```
<remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/>
```

to

```
ex: <remap from="image" to="/group_name/node_name/image_raw"/>

<remap from="image" to="/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw"/>
```

Your code should be like:

```
<launch>
 <group ns="camera1">
  <node name="usb_cam1" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
 </group>

<group ns="camera2">
  <node name="usb_cam2" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video2" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
 </group>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [nelsoncampos](https://answers.ros.org/users/23285/nelsoncampos/) with karma: 46 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on 2020-06-18**:
that helps a little for me, but I still don't understand something: Can I change the topic which each node publishes? I'm using usb_cam too and each node will run in different devices, I need them to publish on different topics so the server can send them instructions individually.